# Meaning of SA mean in "GFI - SA" electrical panel labeling?

Tags: electrical-panel

I noticed a couple of the handwritten labels on my electrical panel are listed as "GFI - SA". I am curious as to what the "SA" indication means. Note, there are also a few other "GFI"-marked labels on my panel without the "SA" moniker. So the "SA" indication is obviously meant to differentiate between them.

Comment: That is now the most ThreePhaseEel question I have ever seen on this site.  Hopefully we'll hear from him soon.

Comment: Can you post photos of the labeling?  Do you know what receptacles and devices those breakers control?

Comment: Is this a location?

Answer (score 2):

In this context, "SA" means "Small Appliance", a specific designation required per the NEC, article 210.52. Dwellings are required to have a minimum number of SA circuits, not to be confused with GFCIs required for outdoor, bathroom and garage circuits. Labeling them that way in the panel makes it easier for an inspector to see so that the electrician can pass the inspection without having to prove to the inspector that he has the proper number of SA circuits.

Comment: +1 I'm willing to bet you're right. My idea is reasonable, but yours is more plausible. Deleting my answer.